# Reshape from long to wide format

Tags: r, reshape

example

```
customer_code    items
1                sugar
1                salt       
2                sugar      
2                accessories
3                salt
```

Desired output

```
customer_code   item   item2       item3
1              sugar   salt     
2              sugar             accessories
3                      salt
```

Comment: The `NA` value in expected output for `des_subcat1` is not making sense as the customer id `3.12E+12` have articulo in `des_subcat` column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `spread` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
  mutate(df1, var=factor(items, levels=unique(items), 
      labels=paste0('items', seq(n_distinct(items))))) %>% 
            spread(var, items, fill='')
#  customer_code items1 items2      items3
#1             1  sugar   salt            
#2             2  sugar        accessories
#3             3          salt
```

Comment: Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows

Comment: @SaugandthData Based on the example provided, I didn't get any errors.  You may need to create a sequence variable for your original dataset as there are duplicates.  You can update the post with a small example that gives the error

Comment: check %>% group_by(customer_code) %>% spread(des_subcat, des_subcat) -> df_wide
Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363), (111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121), (683, 684, 685, 686, 687, 688, 689, 690, 691, 692, 693), (34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 721, 722, 723, 724, 725, 726), (518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528), (474, 475,

Comment: @SaugandhDatta  I already said the reason for the error. If you can update your post with a small example that reproduce the error, I can test it.

Comment: article_code customer_code des_subsettore des_subcat
9014 8.92E+12 GROCERY CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)
9014 8.92E+12 GROCERY CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)
9014 8.92E+12 GROCERY articlo
9014 3.25E+12 GROCERY articlo
9014 3.25E+12 GROCERY CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)
9014 3.25E+12 GROCERY CONDIMENTI PRIMI (PELATI & SUGHI)

Comment: @SaugandhDatta  Please update it in your original post.  It is not easy to copy/paste from the comments as the format is not good

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78731/discussion-between-saugandh-datta-and-akrun).

Answer (score 5):

You can do a simple `dcast` here

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, customer_code ~ paste("items", items, sep = "_"), value.var = "items")
#   customer_code items_accessories items_salt items_sugar
# 1             1              <NA>       salt       sugar
# 2             2       accessories       <NA>       sugar
# 3             3              <NA>       salt        <NA>
```

Or a bit closer to your desired output

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, indx := paste0("items", .GRP), by = items]
dcast(df, customer_code ~ indx, value.var = "items")
#    customer_code items1 items2      items3
# 1:             1  sugar   salt          NA
# 2:             2  sugar     NA accessories
# 3:             3     NA   salt          NA
```

Comment: I like the way you created indx with `.GRP`

Comment: it returns numeric value and identifies only the first item

Comment: So you need to provide s reproducible exsmple because it works on your data

Answer (score 2):

you can try using function `reshape`:

**to get as many columns as there are different items possible:**

```
new_df <- reshape(df, idvar="customer_code", timevar="items", v.names="items", direction="wide")
new_df
#  customer_code items.sugar items.salt items.accessories
#1             1       sugar       salt              <NA>
#3             2       sugar       <NA>       accessories
#5             3        <NA>       salt              <NA>
```

*you can change the column names afterwards with `colnames(new_df)[-1] <- paste0("item", 1:(ncol(new_df)-1))`*

**another option, in case you want to get as many column as the max number of items a unique customer can have:**

```
df_split <- split(df, df[, 1])
df_split <- lapply(df_split, reshape, idvar="customer_code", timevar="items", v.names="items", direction="wide")
max_item <- max(sapply(df_split, ncol))
df_split <- lapply(df_split, function(df){ 
                                 if(ncol(df) < max_item) df <- cbind(df, matrix(NA, ncol=max_item - ncol(df)))
                                 colnames(df)[-1] <- paste0("item", 1:(max_item-1))
                                 return(df)
                              })
new_df <- do.call("rbind", df_split)
new_df
#  customer_code item1       item2
#1             1 sugar        salt
#2             2 sugar accessories
#3             3  salt        <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Packages `dplyr` and especially `tidyr` can solve this kind of problems. This code does the trick.

```
require("tidyr")
require("dplyr")
df %>% group_by(customer_code) %>% spread(items, items) -> df_wide
#   customer_code accessories salt sugar
# 1             1          NA salt sugar
# 2             2 accessories   NA sugar
# 3             3          NA salt    NA
```

Hope there is no problem to change colnames if necessary:

```
names(df_wide)[-1] <- paste0("item", 1:(ncol(df_wide)-1))
#   customer_code       item1 item2 item3
# 1             1          NA  salt sugar
# 2             2 accessories    NA sugar
# 3             3          NA  salt    NA
```

In addition may suggest this form of output (may be convenient):

```
df  %>% mutate(present = T) %>% spread(items, present, fill = F)
#   customer_code accessories  salt sugar
# 1             1       FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# 2             2        TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# 3             3       FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows